# Полный список сотрудников

Tags: access, c, visual-studio

Всем привет! Нужен ваш совет!

К примеру у меня имеется БД (Aсcess), которая подключена к проекту... Все это делается в Visual Studio 2008 и на С.

Как сделать, что бы при нажатие на Button (список сотрудников), появился полный список сотрудников?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос неконкретный. Общий алгоритм такой.

1. Повесить обработчик на нажатие кнопки.
2. Сделать запрос к базе банных и осуществить выборку сотрудников.
3. Отобразить результат запроса - список сотрудников - на форме.